# Range Object Error

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to use Find Function to find 'One site:' From there, I will  clear whatever is on the right. I am facing an application defined error on the line where it is suppose to clear. I think I might have done it wrongly. It would be good if someone told me where I have done it wrongly

```
Dim r As Range 
Set r = Sheet2.Range("E:M").Find(What:="One site:", _ 
After:=Sheet2.Range("E3"), _ 
LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not r Is Nothing Then
r.End(xlRight).ClearContents 'Error on this line 
End If
```

Comment: Put `On Error Resume Next` just before the `.Find`. Then put `On Error GoTo 0` afterwards, otherwise you get another error if it's not found.

Comment: It should be `xlToRight`, not *xlRight* I think that's what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be what you are after, you need to change **xlRight** to **xlToRight**, and a little extra to clear those on the right.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SO45316709()
    Dim r As Range, r2 As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = Sheet2.Range("E:M").Find(What:="One site:", After:=Sheet2.Range("E3"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        Set r2 = r.End(xlToRight)
        Sheet2.Range(r.Offset(0, 1), r2).ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @YowE3K, Could have also use `With Sheet2` to reduce typing.

Answer (score 1):

You need a space before the underscores.

Comment: my code for find function is not split in excel but when i copied here it was split. I added the underscore after that.